# xml serialisation in java?

Tags: java, xml

Ive the foll code snippet

```
class A{
  private int num;
  public ArrayList<Integer> totRecords ;
  public final int getNum(){
    return num;
  }
  public final void setNum(int val){
    num = val;
  }
  // inside main

  {
    A a = new A();
    a.setNum(1);
    a.totRecords.add(0);
    // i use javabeans serialisation.
```

But, the arrylist is not getting serialised. Can someonepls help?
Is it beacuse arraylist does not have getter-settter

or is it beacuse a public member can not be serialised?

Comment: Can you please format your code? There is a little 101010 button to do this :)

Comment: At least put some effort into giving us code that's actually valid Java. Don't just throw something together.

Comment: What lib are you using to serialise?  JAXP, JAXB, XStream, JDOM?

Comment: Have you looked at existing tools that does this for you like XStream? http://xstream.codehaus.org/

Comment: It looks like he uses javabeans for serialization: "// i use javabeans serialisation."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read [Using XMLEncoder](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/persistence4/) to understand its capabilities and limitations.  You will probably need to write a custom persistence delegate.

Comment: @ skaffman -  I'm sorry. I was not given the entire code - only a snippet. Thats what I shared.

Comment: @Martijn Verburg @ javamonkey79 - Yes; I used JavaBeans for serialisation.

Comment: @ CoolBeans - @Jim Garrison - Thanks. I'll try with XStream also.